# how to run job jenkins for app node.js and create-react-app

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have developed an application using create-react-app, I would like to deploy this application to cross a job Jenkins.

Would you have good practices to create a jenkins job that will builder the node application for the package and make it available to some URL ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently faced the same objective and didn't find any information. I figured it out myself and wrote a blog article about it. It doesn't cover automatic upload to an FTP-Space but that shouldn't be an issue, once the automatic build works. Jenkins already as a function to publish artifacts. You can find the article here:

https://blog.torq-dev.de/en/continuous-integration-on-jenkins-for-react-apps-scaffolded-with-create-react-app/